# WSAdmin - Admin App Install: Random string is appended to the Application name

Tags: websphere, wsadmin

I am working on automation script to install a WAR in the Websphere using WSADMIN console. It leaves random string at the end of the application name.

If the application name is 'test.war', name appears as 'test.war1525e76b1cb'. Has anyone come across this issue before? Any solutions worked. I need the application name to match the artifact to use isAppReady and start the application.

Comment: I frequently use AdminApp.install and have never seen this issue.  Can you post the code involving how you are executing AdminApp.install?

Answer (score 2):

I believe not providing specific app name appends random string to the artifact name and sets as application display name. This line of code with -appname option did the trick.

```
AdminApp.install(appPath,['-appname '+app_name+'','-MapWebModToVH', [['.*', '.*', 'default_host']]])
```